# Registration Button

Tags: registration

Good morning,

I am trying to move the Registration Button in our event registration page to somewhere more noticable. Also, I'd like for the button to be bigger.

Can someone help me please?
Evelyn Re'
evelyn@nccyber.org

Comment: This would be done by styling - have you got a theme you are able to edit?

Answer (score 1):

I noticed on [your website](https://www.nccyber.org/) the chapter meeting announcement and see that it's linking to an [Event Info](https://nccyber.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/info?id=7&reset=1) page on CiviCRM Spark.

Since your website already has all of the relevant information, I recommend linking directly to the [Event Registration](https://nccyber.civicrm.org/civicrm/event/register?id=7&reset=1) page.